# Pandas add column with value based on condition based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, conditional-statements

I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image: df]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'age' : [21, 45, 45, 5],
     'salary' : [20, 40, 10, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

and would like to add an extra column called "is_rich" which captures if a person is rich depending on his/her salary. I found multiple ways to accomplish this:

```py
# method 1
df['is_rich_method1'] = np.where(df['salary']>=50, 'yes', 'no')

# method 2
df['is_rich_method2'] = ['yes' if x >= 50 else 'no' for x in df['salary']]

# method 3
df['is_rich_method3'] = 'no'
df.loc[df['salary'] > 50,'is_rich_method3'] = 'yes'
```

resulting in:

[image: df2]

However I don't understand what the preferred way is. Are all methods equally good depending on your application?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the `timeits`, Luke!

[image]

**Conclusion**
List comprehensions perform the best on smaller amounts of data because they incur very little overhead, even though they are not vectorized. OTOH, on larger data, `loc` and `numpy.where` perform better - vectorisation wins the day.

Keep in mind that the applicability of a method depends on your data, the number of conditions, and the data type of your columns. My suggestion is to test various methods on your data before settling on an option.

One sure take away from here, however, is that list comprehensions are pretty competitive—they're implemented in C and are highly optimised for performance.

---

[Benchmarking code, for reference](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/becf21955793bbc23bedd66fc92367d1). Here are the functions being timed:

```
def numpy_where(df):
  return df.assign(is_rich=np.where(df['salary'] >= 50, 'yes', 'no'))

def list_comp(df):
  return df.assign(is_rich=['yes' if x >= 50 else 'no' for x in df['salary']])

def loc(df):
  df = df.assign(is_rich='no')
  df.loc[df['salary'] > 50, 'is_rich'] = 'yes'
  return df
```

Comment: If I want nothing to happen in the else clause of the lis_comp, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Another method is by using the pandas [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) (depending on the use-case [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)) method. First initialize a Series with a default value (chosen as `"no"`) and replace some of them depending on a condition (a little like a mix between `loc[]` and `numpy.where()`).

```py
df['is_rich'] = pd.Series('no', index=df.index).mask(df['salary']>50, 'yes')
```

It is probably the fastest option. For example, for a frame with 10 mil rows, `mask()` option is 40% faster than `loc` option.<sup>1</sup>

I also updated the `perfplot` benchmark in [cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376135/19123103)'s answer to compare how the `mask` method performs compared to the other methods:

[image: res]

---

<sup>1</sup>: The benchmark result that compares `mask` with `loc`.

```py
def mask(df):
    return df.assign(is_rich=pd.Series('no', index=df.index).mask(df['salary']>50, 'yes'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'salary': np.random.rand(10_000_000)*100})

%timeit mask(df)
# 391 ms ± 3.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit loc(df)
# 558 ms ± 75.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
```