# Indentify cells by condition within the same day

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the below Dataframe. How would I do to get an extra column 'flag' with 1's where a day has a age bigger than 90 and only if it happens in 2 consecutive days (48h in this case)? The output should contain 1' on 2 or more days, depending on how many days the condition is met The dataset is much bigger, but I put here just a small portion so you get an idea.

```
                     Age
Dates                   
2019-01-01 00:00:00   29
2019-01-01 01:00:00   56
2019-01-01 02:00:00   82
2019-01-01 03:00:00   13
2019-01-01 04:00:00   35
2019-01-01 05:00:00   53
2019-01-01 06:00:00   25
2019-01-01 07:00:00   23
2019-01-01 08:00:00   21
2019-01-01 09:00:00   12
2019-01-01 10:00:00   15
2019-01-01 11:00:00    9
2019-01-01 12:00:00   13
2019-01-01 13:00:00   87
2019-01-01 14:00:00    9
2019-01-01 15:00:00   63
2019-01-01 16:00:00   62
2019-01-01 17:00:00   52
2019-01-01 18:00:00   43
2019-01-01 19:00:00   77
2019-01-01 20:00:00   95
2019-01-01 21:00:00   79
2019-01-01 22:00:00   77
2019-01-01 23:00:00    5
2019-01-02 00:00:00   78
2019-01-02 01:00:00   41
2019-01-02 02:00:00   10
2019-01-02 03:00:00   10
2019-01-02 04:00:00   88
2019-01-02 05:00:00   19
```

This would be the desired output:

```
                Dates  Age  flag
0  2019-01-01 00:00:00   29     1
1  2019-01-01 01:00:00   56     1
2  2019-01-01 02:00:00   82     1
3  2019-01-01 03:00:00   13     1
4  2019-01-01 04:00:00   35     1
5  2019-01-01 05:00:00   53     1
6  2019-01-01 06:00:00   25     1
7  2019-01-01 07:00:00   23     1
8  2019-01-01 08:00:00   21     1
9  2019-01-01 09:00:00   12     1
10 2019-01-01 10:00:00   15     1
11 2019-01-01 11:00:00    9     1
12 2019-01-01 12:00:00   13     1
13 2019-01-01 13:00:00   87     1
14 2019-01-01 14:00:00    9     1
15 2019-01-01 15:00:00   63     1
16 2019-01-01 16:00:00   62     1
17 2019-01-01 17:00:00   52     1
18 2019-01-01 18:00:00   43     1
19 2019-01-01 19:00:00   77     1
20 2019-01-01 20:00:00   95     1
21 2019-01-01 21:00:00   79     1
22 2019-01-01 22:00:00   77     1
23 2019-01-01 23:00:00    5     1
24 2019-01-02 00:00:00   78     0
25 2019-01-02 01:00:00   41     0
26 2019-01-02 02:00:00   10     0
27 2019-01-02 03:00:00   10     0
28 2019-01-02 04:00:00   88     0
29 2019-01-02 05:00:00   19     0
```

The dates is the index of the dataframe and is incremented by 1h.
thanks

Comment: what do you mean with a date bigger than 90?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375985/pandas-add-column-with-value-based-on-condition-based-on-other-columns

Comment: @min2bro - Are you sure?

Comment: edited @Gio, thanks for pointing out, it was a mistake.

Comment: @jezrael Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375985/pandas-add-column-with-value-based-on-condition-based-on-other-columns

Comment: @ChrisA updated the link in comment, its a duplicate

Comment: @min2bro - 0% match

Comment: @jezrael are we looking for exact question with same data for duplicate? it gives enough clue on how to create a new column based on condition from other column values.

Comment: @min2bro - exactly, it is necessary. Because from dupe is not possible answering this question, so not dupe.

Comment: @min2bro - i try create more repeating dupe list and add to my profile, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first compare column by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), then grouping by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) and ccheck if at least one `True` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html), last cast mask to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping, then combinae it with previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574075/2901002):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': 10}, index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='5H', periods=24))
#for test 1H timestamp use
#df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': 10}, index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='H', periods=24 * 5))
df.loc[pd.Timestamp('2019-01-02 01:00:00'), 'Age'] = 95
df.loc[pd.Timestamp('2019-01-03 02:00:00'), 'Age'] = 95
df.loc[pd.Timestamp('2019-01-05 19:00:00'), 'Age'] = 95
#print (df)

#for test 48 consecutive values change N = 48
N = 10
s = df['Age'].gt(90)
s1 = (s.groupby(df.index.date).transform('any')) 
g1 = s1.ne(s1.shift()).cumsum()
df['flag'] = (s.groupby(g1).transform('size').ge(N) & s1).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
                     Age  flag
2019-01-01 00:00:00   10     0
2019-01-01 05:00:00   10     0
2019-01-01 10:00:00   10     0
2019-01-01 15:00:00   10     0
2019-01-01 20:00:00   10     0
2019-01-02 01:00:00   95     1
2019-01-02 06:00:00   10     1
2019-01-02 11:00:00   10     1
2019-01-02 16:00:00   10     1
2019-01-02 21:00:00   10     1
2019-01-03 02:00:00   95     1
2019-01-03 07:00:00   10     1
2019-01-03 12:00:00   10     1
2019-01-03 17:00:00   10     1
2019-01-03 22:00:00   10     1
2019-01-04 03:00:00   10     0
2019-01-04 08:00:00   10     0
2019-01-04 13:00:00   10     0
2019-01-04 18:00:00   10     0
2019-01-04 23:00:00   10     0
2019-01-05 04:00:00   10     0
2019-01-05 09:00:00   10     0
2019-01-05 14:00:00   10     0
2019-01-05 19:00:00   95     0
```

Comment: the problem is that my index is type `object` hence it does not have `date` attribute

Comment: and If I would have to set 1's only if the above condition is met 2 consecutive days?

Comment: I think something is wrong here. Your code assumes that age needs to be >95 the whole day in order to set it's flag to 1. What I'm trying is that if age >95 ate least  1 hour or more per day during 2 or more consecutive day, then flag = 1

Comment: @Capie - So change `s1 = (s.groupby(df.index.date).transform('all'))` to `s1 = (s.groupby(df.index.date).transform('any'))`

Comment: are you sure ? condition is met on my side many consecutive days and I still get flag =0

Comment: @Capie - not tested, I will do it now

Comment: I tested on your code adding age = 10 to 1 hour everyday and the result is all 0's, so something must be wrong there :(

Comment: @Capie - Change data sample for easy test, also changed `df['flag'] = (s.groupby(g1).transform('size').eq(48) & s1).astype(int)` to `df['flag'] = (s.groupby(g1).transform('size').ge(N) & s1).astype(int)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191531/discussion-between-capie-and-jezrael).

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, this could be a solution to the first version of the question: how to add a column whose row values are 1 if at least one of the rows with the same date (y-m-d) has an Age value greater than 90.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Dates':['2019-01-01 00:00:00',
              '2019-01-01 01:00:00',
              '2019-01-01 02:00:00',
              '2019-01-02 00:00:00',
              '2019-01-02 01:00:00',
              '2019-01-03 02:00:00',
              '2019-01-03 03:00:00',],
     'Age':[29, 56, 92, 13, 1, 2, 93],})
df.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df['flag'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).day
df['flag'] = df.flag.isin(df['flag'][df['Age']>90]).astype(int)
```

It returns:

```
                    Age flag
Dates       
2019-01-01 00:00:00 29  1
2019-01-01 01:00:00 56  1
2019-01-01 02:00:00 92  1
2019-01-02 00:00:00 13  0
2019-01-02 01:00:00 1   0
2019-01-03 02:00:00 2   1
2019-01-03 03:00:00 93  1
```

Comment: Do you check output?

Comment: this will set to 1 every age bigger than 90, not checking the date.